# OAuth2 login provider - endpoint page

Tags: authentication-authorization

I have installed OAUTH login provider and all dependencies to provide authentication service to other web application throug drupal authentication.
The problem is that I still do not manage to test if the drupal auth login provider works correctly. I am not sure what is the URL that I shoud put in the client application to reach the server auth provider.

For example in local development environment if I try

```
https://localhost/oauth2_loginprovider/
```

I get a FORBIDDEN response from Apache while if I try to contact

```
https://localhost/oauth2/ ...
```

I get a 404 page not found on the server

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://localhost/oauth2/authorize ? That is the authorization start point for me.